# Deleteing column if the cell value is x

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in excel, and I am trying to delete a column if value in the cell is x over a range of 10+ columns. Data filtering does not work because it deletes rows.So, I need to choose all columns where cells in a specified row contain value x. I am recording macros and trying to automate that action. Macros code is welcome, but not necessary.Thank you.

Comment: can you show your code - that you have recorded and edited?

Comment: I have not come up with anything. Thats why I am asking.

Comment: You're lucky Siddharth answered - this is more a Q&A site to help coders - not a service for copy/paste freebies

Comment: he answered he got an upvote and I accepted his answer. I think this is one of the reasons he has 29k points as opposed to your 3k.)

P.S. I did alter the code, but thanks to Siddharth I got a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? Paste this code in a module.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rw As Long, i as Long

    '~~> This is the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> This the row where you want to check
    Rw = 1

    With ws
        '~~> I am assuming there are 10 cols. Change as applicable
        For i = 1 To 10
            '~~> UCASE so that it check for x and X
            If UCase(.Cells(Rw, i).Value) = "X" Then
                '~~> Set your range
                If Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set Rng = .Columns(i)
                Else
                    Set Rng = Union(Rng, .Columns(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.Delete Shift:=xlRight
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) Using this method is good because one then doesn't have to delete individual columns which will slow down the code.

Comment: deleteing columns inside the loop wouldn't be great practise and would complicate things and make it a lot less readable

Comment: Looks promising. Imma try it.